# MS-ACCESS Filter Subform with Button

Tags: database, ms-access

I am trying to do something I imagine is very trivial. I was able to do this using a ComboBox, but have switched to using SubForms, due to the ease of conditional formatting.

Form = Expiring

SubForm = CORE2

Fields = [Core], [Active]

Button = CoreSearch

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub CoreSearch_Click()

Dim Task As String

Me.Refresh

Task = "SELECT * FROM CORE2.Expiring WHERE DateDiff('m', [Core RS], Date()) > 36 And [Active] = True"

DoCmd.ApplyFilter Task

End Sub
```

I keep getting `The action of method is invalid because the form or report isn't bound to a table or query`. Is this because I am not specifying where to apply the filter?

Comment: I have never used ApplyFilter. Can set RecordSource property with a SELECT sql statement. Or set form Filter and FilterOn properties with the criteria from the WHERE clause. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html.

Comment: All code modules should have `Option Explicit` in header to force variable declaration. Can set application options to do this by default in new modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any example that uses the FilterName argument, they all use the WHERE Condition argument.

ApplyFilter acts on whatever form the code is behind.

Assuming button is on form CORE2.

`DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "DateDiff('m', [Core RS], Date()) > 36 And [Active] = True"`

Alternatively:

```
Me.Filter = "DateDiff('m', [Core RS], Date()) > 36 And [Active] = True"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Suggest naming subform/subreport container control different from the object it holds, such as ctrCore. If button is on main form and you want to apply filter to subform:

```
Me.ctrCore.Form.Filter = "DateDiff('m', [Core RS], Date()) > 36 And [Active] = True"
Me.ctrCore.Form.FilterOn = True
```